# Preserving complex view model data between post requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a master view model that contains various other view models, including lists of other view models. I can preserve the state of the master view model by using lots of `@Html.HiddenFor()` statements in views, however this seems untidy, especially when doing so basically reconstructs each member field with the view model. Is there a 'better' way or is this the most common method?

It would be great if a catch all `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.viewModel)` automatically included all members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a better practice to just save the primary keys of objects in hidden fields and re-fetch the data on a POST request. The same counts for populating lists. I usually create a method which takes care of populating my view model with data and call this on both my GET and POST actions.

Comment: I thought about this way as it suits stateless practices, my concern was the heavy use of database calls.

Comment: @Lee you could look into caching if performance is an issue. But I think you shouldn't be afraid of some extra database calls, a clean application design is more important in my opinion.